# transposed Pandas data frame zeroth column not callable as [:, 0]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use Seaborn to plot a simple bar plot using data that was transformed. The data started out looking like this (text follows):[image: initial]

element 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
C   95.6    95.81   96.1    95.89   97.92   96.71   96.1    96.38   96.09   97.12   95.12   95.97

N   1.9 1.55    1.59    1.66    0.53    1.22    1.57    1.63    1.82    0.83    2.37    2.13

O   2.31    2.4 2.14    2.25    1.36    1.89    2.23    1.8 1.93    1.89    2.3 1.71

Co  0.18    0.21    0.16    0.17    0.01    0.03    0.13    0.01    0.02    0.01    0.14    0.01

Zn  0.01    0.03    0.02    0.03    0.18    0.14    0.07    0.17    0.14    0.16    0.07    0.18

and after importing using:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\path.txt", sep='\t',header = 0, usecols=[0, 1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], index_col='element').transpose()
display(df1)
```

[image: after transpose]

When I plot the values of an element versus the first column (which represents an observation), the first column of data corresponding to 'C' is used instead. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

I also tried importing, then pivoting the dataframe, which resulted in an undesired shape that repeated the element set as columns 12 times.

```
ax = sns.barplot(x=df1.iloc[:,0], y='Zn', data=df1)
```

[image]

edited to add that I am not married to using any particular package or technique. I just want to be able to use my data to build a bar plot with 1-12 on the x axis and elemental compositions on the y.

Comment: @BigBen i hope that works

Comment: you want the barplot to be `'element'` as x and `'Zn'` (or other columns) as y ?

Comment: I would like the x axis to be numbered 1 through 12 and I'll build the bar plot on the percent composition of some of the elements. Ultimately I plan to explore the data by building stacked bar plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have different possibilities here. The problem you have is because `'element'` is the index of your dataframe, so `x=df1.iloc[:,0]` is the column of `'C'`.

1)

```
ax = sns.barplot(x=df.index, y='Zn', data=df1)
```

2. 

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True) #now 'element' is the first column of the df1
ax = sns.barplot(x=df.iloc[:,0], y='Zn', data=df1)

#equal to
ax = sns.barplot(x='element', y='Zn', data=df1
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! I used your #1 answer.